# trouble getting correct answer when dividing by a decimal

Tags: c

This is my first course in coding. I get errors when I choose the number 3 in the selection. That is, if I divide the 12 by 2 the program gives the correct output, if however, I divide 10.4 by 2 the program output just goes into a loop until  I stop the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* variable definition: */

    int intValue, menuSelect, results;
    float shrink;

    intValue = 1; 
    // While a positive number
    while (intValue > 0) {    
        printf("Enter a positive Integer\n: ");
        scanf("%d", &intValue);
        {
            printf("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, or 3 to divide  input by 2, to end program enter a negative integer.\n: ");
            scanf("%d", &menuSelect);
            if (menuSelect == 1) {
                // Call the Square Function
                results = Square(intValue);
                printf("Square of %d is %d\n", intValue, results);
            } else
            if (menuSelect == 2) {
                // Call the Cube function
                results = Cube(intValue);
                printf("Cube of %d is %d\n", intValue, results);
            } else
            if (menuSelect == 3) {
                // Call the Divisor function
                results = Shrink (intValue);
                printf("The quotient of %d is %d\n", intValue, results);
            } else 
                printf("Invalid menu item, only 1, 2 or 3 is accepted\n");
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}

/* function returning the Square of a number */
int Square(int value) {
    return value * value;
}

/* function returning the Cube of a number */
int Cube(int value) {
    return value * value * value;
}

/* function returning the quotient of a number */
int Shrink(int value) {
    return (double)value / 2;
}
```

Comment: Hm. `Shrink` returns an `int`, right?

Comment: What did you learn when you stepped through this in a debugger?

Comment: How did you divide 10.4 by 2? `10.4` is not a valid input for `%d` and it cannot be stored in `int`.

Comment: @ user3121023, correct it keeps getting stuck. @MikeCAT, %d was changed to %g still gets stuck.

Comment: Use correct type to store data read. `int` is not for storing data read via `%g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off whats the

> floatshrink;

In line two of the main, your program shouldn't even compile.

The problems that you're having is

1)You can't input floats to your program. Your variables are all integers, and you're only scanning for ints.

> int intValue, menuSelect, results;
>
> //(...)
>
> scanf("%d", &intValue);

2) Your function returns only integers so you'll lose the decimal part anyways.

```
int Shrink(int value)
{
return (double)value/2;

}
```

3) Don't forget your headers!! The compiler needs to know what to expect

```
double Square(double value);

/* function returning the Cube of a numnber */
double Cube(double value);

/* function returning the quotient of a number */
double Shrink(double value);
```

Last of you got some basic problems with indentation don't worry about it you'll get a hang of it soon 
Here's a corrected version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


double Square(double value);

/* function returning the Cube of a numnber */
double Cube(double value);

/* function returning the quotient of a number */
double Shrink(double value);


int main (void )
{
    /* variable definition: */

    float numer_input,results;
    int menuSelect;
    //floatshrink; (no idea what this is)

    numer_input = 1; //you could use a do while statement to avoid this 
    // While a positive number
    while ( numer_input> 0)
    {    
        printf ("Enter a positive Integer\n: ");
        scanf("%f", &numer_input);


        printf ("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, or 3 to divide  input by 2, to end program enter a negative integer.\n: ");
        scanf("%d", &menuSelect);
        if (menuSelect == 1)
        {
        // Call the Square Function
            results = Square(numer_input);
            printf("Square of %f is %f\n",numer_input, results);
        }
        else if (menuSelect == 2)
        {
        // Call the Cube function
            results = Cube(numer_input);
            printf("Cube of %f is %f\n",numer_input, results);
        }
        else if (menuSelect == 3)
        {
        // Call the Divisor function
            results = Shrink (numer_input);
            printf("The quotient of %f is %f\n", numer_input, results);
        }
        else 
            printf("Invalid menu item, only 1, 2 or 3 is accepted\n");

    }   

    return 0;
}

/* function returning the Square of a number */
double Square(double value){
    return value*value;
}

/* function returning the Cube of a numnber */
double Cube(double value){
    return value*value*value;
}

/* function returning the quotient of a number */
double Shrink(double value){
    return (double)value/2;
}
```

Lastly I'd recommend using a switch statement as the code will seems much more clearer than with the if and else if , but that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `float` or `double` values to store floating point numbers accurately and your `Shrink` function must return `float` or `double`, not `int`.  The `printf` format needs adjusting too.

Furthermore, you must define or at least declare the functions before they are used in `main`.

Here is a corrected version.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function returning the Square of a number */
int Square(int value) {
    return value * value;
}

/* function returning the Cube of a number */
int Cube(int value) {
    return value * value * value;
}

/* function returning the quotient of a number */
double Shrink(int value) {
    return (double)value / 2;
}

int main() {
    /* variable definition: */

    int intValue, menuSelect, results;
    double shrink;

    intValue = 1; 
    // While a positive number
    while (intValue > 0) {    
        printf("Enter a positive Integer\n: ");
        scanf("%d", &intValue);
        {
            printf("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, or 3 to divide  input by 2, to end program enter a negative integer.\n: ");
            scanf("%d", &menuSelect);
            if (menuSelect == 1) {
                // Call the Square Function
                results = Square(intValue);
                printf("Square of %d is %d\n", intValue, results);
            } else
            if (menuSelect == 2) {
                // Call the Cube function
                results = Cube(intValue);
                printf("Cube of %d is %d\n", intValue, results);
            } else
            if (menuSelect == 3) {
                // Call the Divisor function
                shrink = Shrink(intValue);
                printf("The quotient of %d is %g\n", intValue, shrink);
            } else {
                printf("Invalid menu item, only 1, 2 or 3 is accepted\n");
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```